# proper date input for pandas datareader?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, pandas-datareader

Both date formats below (string or datetime) used to work. However, in the last few days these lines only output the *last year*'s worth of data, regardless the year I specify (here 2012):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2012,12,31)
df = wb.DataReader ('GE', 'google', '2012, 1, 1', '2012, 12, 31') # doesn't work
print (df)
df2 = wb.DataReader ('GE', 'google', start, end) # doesn't work
print (df2)
```

abbreviated output for both:

```
            Open   High    Low  Close    Volume
Date                                            
2016-09-15  29.55  29.85  29.42  29.75  35262527
...
2017-09-13  23.93  24.18  23.92  24.11  38629676
```

Answer (score 0):

during the process of fixing this, i upgraded to the most current version of pandas (0.20.3) and pandas-datareader (0.5.0).  that did not fix the code in the question.  the problem appears to be trying to use google as the source.  the code below runs correctly but uses yahoo as the source.  however, it fails when trying to use google as the source.

```
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
from datetime import date
start = date (2012, 1, 1)
end = date (2012, 12, 31)
df = data.DataReader ('GE', 'yahoo', start, end)
print (df)
```

Comment: This looks like worthy additional information that should be integrated into the question, in the what have you tried section.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import yfinance as yfin
    import datetime

    start = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1)
    end   = datetime.datetime(2012,12,31)

    tickerGE2 = yfin.Ticker('GE')
    dfGE2 = tickerGE2.history(  period="max", start=start, end=end)
    print (dfGE2)
```

Sample output

```
                             Open        High         Low       Close  \
```

Date
2012-01-03 00:00:00-05:00   85.363812   86.628115   85.363812   85.972549
2012-01-04 00:00:00-05:00   85.738404   87.096361   85.597928   86.909058
2012-01-05 00:00:00-05:00   86.440802   87.096367   85.644761   86.862236

Comment: While their content may be valid, code-only answers get poor reception on SO. Please see [answer] for good tips.